# rdf reasoning rules via Jena

Tags: jena, reasoning, jena-rules

I want to express this relation: if article X has author Y, and the author has the influenceFactor medium or high(3 classes: low , medium, high) then this article is regarded as highly recommended.

```
(?x computer-science#hasAuthor ?y)(?y computer-science#hasInfluenceFactor computer-science#High) -> (?x computer-science#isImportant computer-science#importantfactor)
```

is my thought right?

here is some snippet of the ontology

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasAuthor">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    <owl:propertyDisjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#isAuthorOf"/>
    <rdfs:range>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasAuthor"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#author"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:domain>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasAuthor"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#article"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:domain>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
   <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasInfluenceFactor">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#author"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#influenceFator"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#High">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#influenceFator"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#isImportant">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#importantFactor"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#influenceFator"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#importantFactor">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#importantFactor"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

sincere thanks to any viewer of my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a rule to express your ontology, you can do it entirely in OWL. First we define an ontology based on your example, but with some new axioms. In particular, we define two new class expressions: `InfluentialArticle` and `ImportantArticle`. An influential article has high or medium impact, an important author wrote at least one influential article:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix cs: <http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#>.

# properties
cs:hasAuthor
  a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain cs:Article ;
  rdfs:range cs:Author .

cs:wrote
  a owl:ObjectPropert ;
  owl:inverseOf cs:hasAuthor .

# classes
cs:hasInfluenceFactor
  a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain cs:Article ;
  rdfs:range cs:InfluenceFactor .

cs:InfluenceFactor
  owl:equivalentClass
    [a owl:Class ;
     owl:oneOf ( cs:high cs:medium cs:low )
    ].

cs:Author a owl:Class.
cs:Article a owl:Class.

# axioms

# an influential article has a high or medium impact
cs:InfluentialArticle
  rdfs:subClassOf cs:Article ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
    owl:unionOf (
      [a owl:Restriction ;
       owl:onProperty cs:hasInfluenceFactor ;
       owl:hasValue cs:high]
      [a owl:Restriction ;
       owl:onProperty cs:hasInfluenceFactor ;
       owl:hasValue cs:medium
      ]
    )
  ].

# an important author wrote an influential article
cs:ImportantAuthor
  rdfs:subClassOf cs:Author ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty cs:wrote ;
    owl:someValuesFrom cs:InfluentialArticle
  ].

# individuals

# fred wrote a lousy paper
cs:fred
  a cs:Author.
cs:article1
  a cs:Article ;
  cs:hasInfluenceFactor cs:low ;
  cs:hasAuthor cs:fred.

# jane wrote a good paper
cs:jane
  a cs:Author.
cs:article2
  a cs:Article ;
  cs:hasInfluenceFactor cs:high ;
  cs:hasAuthor cs:jane.
```

Now we can write some Jena code to load this ontology and process it with a built-in reasoner:

```
package examples;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class ReasonerExample
{
    String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new ReasonerExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF );
        FileManager.get().readModel( m, "src/main/resources/comp-sci.ttl" );

        // list all authors
        System.out.println( "All authors:" );
        OntClass author = m.getOntClass( NS + "Author" );
        for (Iterator<? extends OntResource> i = author.listInstances(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.println( "  " + i.next().getURI() );
        }

        // list high impact authors
        OntClass importantAuthor = m.getOntClass( NS + "ImportantAuthor" );
        System.out.println( "Important authors:" );
        for (Iterator<? extends OntResource> i = importantAuthor.listInstances(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.println( "  " + i.next().getURI() );
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
All authors:
  http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#jane
  http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#fred
Important authors:
  http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#jane
```

Note I also fixed your names to use OWL conventions: leading capital letter for classes, lower case for everything else. I also simplified the domain and range constraints, which were a bit weird.

**Update**

Following a comment from the original poster, I translated the ontology to RDF/XML using Jena's `rdfcat` tool as follows:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:cs="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Article"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Author"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasAuthor">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Article"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Author"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasInfluenceFactor">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Article"/>
    <rdfs:range>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#InfluenceFactor">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
          <owl:Class>
            <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#high"/>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#medium"/>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#low"/>
            </owl:oneOf>
          </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdfs:range>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#ImportantAuthor">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Author"/>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectPropert rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#wrote">
            <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasAuthor"/>
          </owl:ObjectPropert>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#InfluentialArticle">
            <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#Article"/>
            <owl:equivalentClass rdf:parseType="Resource">
              <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                  <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasInfluenceFactor"/>
                  <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#high"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                  <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#hasInfluenceFactor"/>
                  <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#medium"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
              </owl:unionOf>
            </owl:equivalentClass>
          </rdf:Description>
        </owl:someValuesFrom>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </rdf:Description>
  <cs:Article rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#article2">
    <cs:hasInfluenceFactor rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#high"/>
    <cs:hasAuthor>
      <cs:Author rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#jane"/>
    </cs:hasAuthor>
  </cs:Article>
  <cs:Article rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#article1">
    <cs:hasInfluenceFactor rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#low"/>
    <cs:hasAuthor>
      <cs:Author rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aero/ontologies/2013/1/computer-science#fred"/>
    </cs:hasAuthor>
  </cs:Article>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: hi Ian @Ian Dickinson thank you for such elaborate introductions. I think   I grasped what you said but...I know it is really really stupid, where can I integrate these axioms into my ontology file in RDF/XML format? I used protege 4.2 to create the domain ontology. would your mind giving me some further information to complete this? thank you

Comment: Well, Protégé ought to be able to read Turtle format as well as RDF/XML. However, I've translated the ontology to RDF/XML for you, using Jena's rdfcat. See the updated version of the answer for the RDF/XML.

Comment: clear. thank you very much Ian, you've done me a great favor :)